# Нужно вывести список времени создания файлов в папке

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime



creation_time_list = []

for adress, dirs, files in os.walk(f'D:\\programming\\D\\'):


    for file in files:
        print(file)
        c_time = os.path.getctime(f'D:\\programming\\D\\{file}')
    

        dt_c = datetime.fromtimestamp(c_time).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    
        creation_time_list.append(dt_c)
    
print(creation_time_list)


14.txt
15.txt
1.bmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\programming\ПАРСЕР ВРЕМЯ — копия.py", line 14, in <module>
c_time = os.path.getctime(f'D:\\programming\\D\\{file}')
File "<frozen genericpath>", line 65, in getctime
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 
'D:\\programming\\D\\1.bmp'
```

Comment: Указывайте полный путь к файлу, а не только имя

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime

creation_time_list = []

for addresses, dirs, files in os.walk('ПУТЬ ДО ПАПКИ'):
    for file in os.listdir(addresses):
        c_time = os.path.getctime(f'{addresses}\{file}')
        dt_c = datetime.fromtimestamp(c_time).strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
        creation_time_list.append(dt_c)

print(creation_time_list)
```

Если нужно вывести только время, то замените

```py
dt_c = datetime.fromtimestamp(c_time).strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
```

на

```py
dt_c = datetime.fromtimestamp(c_time).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Как в данном случае мне вывести время создания всех файлов в папке, а не конкретного файла?

Comment: @Илья вам нужна полностью дата или только время?

Comment: @Tamada `os.path.getctime` работает и с относительными путями.

Comment: @Nyuhnyash буду знать

Comment: @Tamada Мне нужны те значения которые  выводит метод os.path.getctime, только вывести эти значения для всех файлов в папке.. То есть когда я ввожу путь к файлу метод мне возвращает значение, а когда пробую через оператор for как в моем коде вывести эти значения для каждого файла выводит ошибку то файл не найден

Comment: @Илья Вы пробовали указывать путь как в моём коде? Если Вам нужно именно значение `os.path.getctime`, то уберите в моём коде строку с `dt_c` и в список добавляйте `c_time`

Comment: @Илья ну и как Вы сами сказали - с указанием полного пути у Вас работает. Попробуйте мой вариант - тут для каждого файла, как Вам и требуется, всё считается с использованием полного пути до файла. Если Вас смущает `{file}` в цикле - это не вручную указанное имя файла. Просто замените `ПУТЬ ДО ПАПКИ` на Ваш

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!

Comment: @Tamada Вы знаете, только досмотрел, что print(creation_time_list) в итоге выводит список состоящий из времени создания папки которая указана как ПУТЬ ДО ПАПКИ, в кол-ве файлов в этой самой папке....То есть у меня в папке всего шесть файлов в итоге с списке шесть раз указано время создания папки, указанной как ПУТЬ ДО ПАПКИ, а не файлов находящихся в этой папке..я хочу увидеть время создания каждого файла по отдельности,  6 разных значений

Comment: @Илья покажите Ваш код, пожалуйста. И покажите, что выводит цикл `for`, если в нём на печать вывести `file`

Comment: @Tamada изменил в самом вверху код,

Comment: @Илья а где у Вас `{file}` в строке `c_time = os.path.getctime(f'D:\\programming\\D')` ? Он Вам и выводит дату создания папки, потому что Вы не указываете файл ему. У меня после `ПУТЬ ДО ПАПКИ` стоит `\{file}`

Comment: @Tamada Изменил коды выше, выдало время создания другого ОДНОГО файла, а мне нужны время каждого ПО ОТДЕЛЬНОСТИ оно разное, там 6 файлов в папке как показывает 'print(file)'

Comment: @Илья так ну ведь Вы неправильно делаете... У Вас должно быть `for adress, dirs, files in os.walk('D:\\programming\\D'):` и `c_time = os.path.getctime(f'D:\\programming\\D\\{file}')`. Вот вставьте без изменений эти строчки себе

Comment: @Tamada сделал как вы сказали, все работает при условии что в папку D положить 6 файлов (спасибо огромное!!!!), но изначально у меня в папке D было 2 файла и еще две папки в которых по 2 файла - всего 6 файлов и в таком случае код не работает, сейчас покажу что пишет вверху

Comment: @Илья а, у Вас есть ещё папки в папке. Несколько минут, попробую исправить

Comment: @Илья, посмотрите выше, изменил код

Comment: @Tamada да, все работает как надо.. символ f в пути `(f'{addresses}\{file}')` означает что эта строка форматируется в процессе выполнения цикла `for file in os.listdir(addresses)` ?

Comment: @Илья `f` перед строкой означает, что это f-строка. Это один из типов форматирования строк. Такие строки позволяют подставлять переменные из области видимости в строку сразу и без лишних конкатенаций